# Decomposition of a diagonal matrix $\Lambda \approx A\Sigma A^T$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I want to decompose a diagonal matrix $\Lambda \in R^{n \times n}$ such that $$ \Lambda \approx A\Sigma A^T $$ where $\Sigma \in R^{k \times k}$ is a diagonal matrix and $A \in R^{n \times k}$ is a dense matrix (or it is non-diagonal matrix), and $k < n$. Is there any decomposition which can be used to solve the above problem?

Edit: Here the approximation implies that  $\|\Lambda - A\Sigma A^T\|_F^2$ should be as low as possible.

Comment: I think it is impossible as we have orthogonal columns... In a slightly circular way of dealing with this we can get the truncated SVD of the matrix $\Lambda \approx U\Sigma V^T$ and that will allow us to select the $\Sigma$ such that it include the maximal absolute values of our $\Lambda$ and $A$ (i.e. $U$) will be just encode the row and the sign of the of the values of $\Sigma$...

Comment: @usεr11852 If I do SVD, then I will get diagonal $A$.

Comment: It won't be necessarily diagonal. Just it will have a single non-zero value per row. But, OK, we are just playing with words now. :)

Comment: Re the edit: as you surely know, the solution to the less restricted problem of approximating $\Lambda$ as $U\Sigma V^\prime$ is given by the SVD.  In this case the SVD yields $\Sigma=\Lambda$ (up to permutation), so all you need to do is remove the smallest $n-k$ singular values, which can be written in the form you require, whence the SVD does the trick.

Comment: @whuber SVD won't give the solution where $A$ is a dense matrix

Comment: You have stated that $\Lambda$ is a *diagonal* matrix.  You haven't specified $A$ in the problem--it's part of the solution.  If you really want $A$ to be "non-diagonal" or "dense," then simply put infinitesimal numbers in the off-diagonal positions.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I'm looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$, its rank is the number of non-zero diagonal elements. If $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{\text{rank}} \rank(\Lambda)>k$, then equality is impossible since
$$ \rank\left(A\Sigma A^T\right)\le \min\left\{ \rank A, \rank\Sigma , \rank A^T\right \}  \le k
$$
so
$$
   \rank\left\{ A\Sigma A^T \right \} < \rank \Lambda.
$$
But you didn't ask about equality, but used $\approx$ symbol without explaining in what sense there should be approximation. So then the question is unclear, but at least equality is impossible and any approximation would loose rank.

Comment: Yes you are right, there won't be any equality that is why I used approximation. I updated the question to make everything more clear.